# Confusion matrix with dask

Tags: dask

I am trying to compute the confusion matrix elements using Dask.
My implementation from an algorithmic point of view seems to be ok.
However, when I run it on 2 arrays of size 1 million each, it takes forever.

Does any one has suggestions on how to optimize this code?

```
def confusion_matrix_dask(truth,predictions,labels_list=[]):
    TP=0
    FP=0
    FN=0
    TN=0
    if not labels_list:
        TP=(truth[predictions==1]==1).sum()
        FP=(truth[predictions!=1]==1).sum()
        TN=(truth[predictions!=1]!=1).sum()
        FN=(truth[predictions==1]!=1).sum()
    for label in labels_list:
        TP=(truth[predictions==label]==label).sum()+TP
        FP=(truth[predictions!=label]==label).sum()+FP
        TN=(truth[predictions!=label]!=label).sum()+TN
        FN=(truth[predictions==label]!=label).sum()+FN


    return np.array([[TN.compute(), FP.compute()] , [TN.compute() ,FN.compute()]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick improvement you should be aware of:

```
import dask
TP, FP, TN, FN = dask.compute(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

instead of calling `.compute()` on each. This will share common data and tasks, and so cut down the total work to be done.